# Changing style of all td elements in specific rows given tr id

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I got specific `tr` id from a `for` loop:

`let rowId = viewPermissionDataTable.getTbodyEl().childNodes[i+1].id;`

My attempts to add border to all `td` in specific `tr`:

1. Not working.

```
$('#rowId td').each(function() {
    $('td').css('border-top', '1px solid #7f7f7f');
});
```

2. All rows got styled instead.

```
$('#' + rowId).each(function() {
    $('td').css('border-top', '1px solid #7f7f7f');
});
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you share html code as well?

Comment: $('#rowId td').css('border-top', '1px solid #7f7f7f') willl work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#" + rowId).find("td").css("border-top", "1px solid #7f7f7f");
```

---

- `$('#' + rowId)` gets the `tr` element.
- `.find("td")` gets all `td` elements nested in your `tr` element.
- `.css("border-top", "1px solid #7f7f7f")` applies the relevant styles to your `td` elements.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to iterate all the "td" child of the `"tr"` unless you have to filter the application of `css`.

Even that approach would work if you consider `this` context in the `$.each`. Currently, it is being applied to all `"td"` elements.

```js
$('#target td').css('border-top', '1px solid #7f7f7f');
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="target">
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Considering your approach with `this` context**

```js
$('#target').each(function() {
  $("td", this).css('border-top', '1px solid #7f7f7f');
});

//OR using just `this` in the callback and selecting `td` elements in selector

/*$('#target td').each(function() {
  $(this).css('border-top', '1px solid #7f7f7f');
});*/
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="target">
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have miss `' td'` `$('#' + rowId)` will be `$('#' + rowId+ ' td')`

```
 $('#' + rowId+ ' td').each(function() {
     $('td').css('border-top', '1px solid #7f7f7f');
 });
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. You may want to take a look at [answer].

Comment: @mmgross Thanks for the recommendation. I have updated my answer.